# To Generate a split indices for n-fold

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a requirement to generate a split for cross validation, say s is an index of records

```
s = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
```

Now I want to randomly shuffle and split the data with 5 folds, typically I want output something like this

```
s = [[1 5 4 6], [2,3, 19,20], [... ], [... ], [.. ]]
```

Note: In each array numbers should be unique, it should not repeat

I know I can use chunk() but in chunk you can do only sequence wise like 1-4, 5-8,....

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried out already for your requirement? Can you indicate which areas are giving you difficulty, and/or any error messages you might be receiving?

Comment: I tried all this but nothing satisfy my requirement http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: Can data repeat amongst different chunks?

Answer (score 9):

Shuffle your array using `random.shuffle` and split it into 5 pieces:

For `Python2` use

```
import random

s = range(1, 21)
random.shuffle(s)
s = [s[i::5] for i in range(5)]
```

or for `Python3`:

```py
import random

s = list(range(1, 21))
random.shuffle(s)
s = [s[i::5] for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Doesn't this split into 4 pieces? The last line should just be `s = [s[i::5] for i in xrange(5)]`

Comment: No it does't. It splits the list into 5 pieces. `len(s)/5` is the number of elements (4 in the case of 20 total) in one fold. And `[i::5]` reads every fifth element, not every forth. So the code is correct.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak Here's the code (although in Python 3), which is as expected. It translates over to Python 2, right? https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLq1jBViE6UyEtv0ghUyEzDySenqphZKAZywVRolecUZqWlpOqUawJUVwcnWllZRqLrsUUqKOgKDOvBKjw/38A

Comment: @BenjaminWang My apologies! Of course you are correct. It should be `range(5)`. I feel stupid now. Thanks for educating me though...

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
s = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
print [random.sample(s,5) for i in xrange(len(s)/5)]
```

Comment: This isn't satisfy requirement in question: `In each array numbers should be unique, it should not repeat.`

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov yes it was added later...had asked the same to OP as well...+1 to ur nice and neat solution